What to do about operator scalability?
Suppose I have a 32 qubit register meant to represent a classic variable. I want to apply gates to it and naturally I have to tensor product up to a 32 bit register. That means something like
$$
I_{1} \otimes ... I_{32} \otimes X
$$
Is required. If this is true then operators scale exponentially with the entangled superposition. That can't be, because then the use cases of a quantum computer would be moot. Can anyone speak for what is conventionally done about this?

To some extent, you are answering your own question. Yes, the size of that matrix will grow exponentially, but you only care about that exponential growth if you are trying to simulate a quantum system using a classical computer. In a quantum computer, the work is being performed by a quantum device that has the ability to handle this exponentiality by branching and recombining any required superpositions. This is precisely why classical computers can't efficiently simulate quantum systems.

"A device that has the ability to handle this exponentiality by branching and recombining any required superpositions" - this is the answer to my question. What is the interface to this device? Is it not programmable classically? If not, then how?

It is programmed classically by passing information about the gates you want to apply. So, in your example, all it would take is to tell the device to apply an X gate to the last qubit. You don’t pass this in the form of a matrix though. Just instructions per qubit

also, the cost of the X gate generally doesn't go up, just because we have a tensor product of many identity gates, i.e. applying the X operator to a single gate should be the same cost, regardless of how many other qubits there are
